# Animation Text Duration

Tags: css, css-animations

I've tried many things however, I cannot control the animation duration. Basically, I would like to show my every animated text for 2-3 seconds. My text is animated too fast. How can I fix that? Note: the place of the animated text is not important.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: -4%;
  padding: 2em 5em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.wrapper p {
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.wrapper b {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
}

.wrapper .animationText {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ac1101;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  40% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  60% {
    top: -150px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <b>
      <div class="animationText">
              anime text 1<br>
        anime text 2
      </div>
        </b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: -4%;
  padding: 2em 5em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.wrapper p {
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.wrapper .b {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
}

.wrapper .animationText {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ac1101;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,30% {
    top: 0%;
  }
  60%,100% {
    top:-100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="animationText">
      anime text 1<br> anime text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look nice as you can see. I am looking for a more proper solution, thanks.

Comment: @blocker maybe you can explain better what you want. You said you want to slow the animation and this is what is done, no?

Comment: Sorry @TemaniAfif  maybe this can help you: https://codepen.io/yemon/pen/pWoROm In this example "work", "lifestyle" and "everything" texts are shown for 2-3 seconds on the screen, after that animation continues..

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `animation-delay` longer.

Comment: Nope. It will affect only once. After the first animation,  the animated text will not stop for  2-3 seconds.